# How to loosely couple chained algorithms

Tags: design, python, machine-learning

I have a search algorithm that is used in conjunction with a machine learning algorithm. I separated the two because I wanted to be able to swap out search algorithms on the fly. However, the coupling is currently too tight. It looks something like:

```
class ML_Algorithm:

    def __init__(self,observers):
        import someMlLibrary
        self.observers = observers 
        self.classifier = someMlLibrary.model()
        self.searchWindow = SearchingWindow(self.__Classify)


    def Train(self, trainingData):
        preprocessedOutput = self.__Preprocess(trainingData)
        transformedOutput = self.__Transform(preprocessedOutput)
        self.classifier.fit(transformedOutput)


    def __call__(self, data):
        # The main entry point for all the processing
        self.searchWindow.AddData(data)
        for output in searchWindow:
           self.UpdateObservers(output)

    def __Classify(self, dataSubset):
        preprocessedOutput = self.__Preprocess(dataSubset)
        transformedOutput = self.__Transform(preprocessedOutput)
        return self.classifier.predict(transformedOutput)

    def __Prepocess(self,data):
        import someLibrary
        return someLibrary.doSomething(data)

    def __Transform(self,data):
        import someOtherLibrary
        return someOtherLibrary.doSomething(data)


    def UpdateObservers(self, output):
        for observer in self.observers:
            observer.OnOutput(output)

class Observer:

    def OnOutput(self, output):
        pass

class SearchingWindow:
    def __init__(self, fn, negativeResult=0):
        from collections import deque 
        self.fn = fn
        self.buffer = deque(maxlen=1000)
        self.negativeResult = negativeResult

    def AddData(self, data):
        self.buffer.extend(data)

    def __iter__(self):
         start = 0
         step = 1
         stop = 3*step
         while notDone:
            start, stop, step = self.GetNextStartStopStep(start, stop, step)
            for i in range(start,stop,step):
                dataSubset = self.buffer[start:stop]
                result1, result2, ..., resultN = self.fn(dataSubset)
                if result1 != self.negativeResult:
                    yield dataSubset
```

I realized the tight coupling when I wanted to access result1, ..., resultN to do some diagnostics through the ML_Algorithm object but couldn't.

Any help is much and truly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is often referred to as the strategy pattern. You want to have a strategy for searching, that is easy to swap out. The easiest way to implement this is to accept the search strategy in the constructor of your main class.

```
class MyFavoriteAlgorithm:
    def __init__(self, observers, search_algorithm):
        .
        .
        self.search_algorithm = search_algorithm
```

As long as all the search strategies interface the same way with your code, this will allow you to swap out different search algorithms whenever you want. You can even leave a default search algorithm if there's one you want to use more often.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the approach used, by doing the following:

- Make the ML algorithm class simpler: put only train, classify, preprocess and transform methods (remove the observers and concrete reference to search window);
- Put the observers stuff into the SearchingWindow;
- Inject a ML classifier into the Searching window, it needs to implement the same interface (Train/Classify methods)
- Place the entry point for processing into the SearchingWindow (or somewhere else, just please remove it from ML_Algorithm!)

---

Here's some code to illustrate my suggestion:

```py
#Represents a classification method, therefore it only
#contains methods for training, preprocessing, feature transformation
#and classification
class ML_Algorithm:
    def __init__(self,observers):
        import someMlLibrary
        self.classifier = someMlLibrary.model()

    def Train(self, trainingData):
        preprocessedOutput = self.__Preprocess(trainingData)
        transformedOutput = self.__Transform(preprocessedOutput)
        self.classifier.fit(transformedOutput)

    def Classify(self, dataSubset): #public
        preprocessedOutput = self.__Preprocess(dataSubset)
        transformedOutput = self.__Transform(preprocessedOutput)
        return self.classifier.predict(transformedOutput)

    def __Prepocess(self,data):
        import someLibrary
        return someLibrary.doSomething(data)

    def __Transform(self,data):
        import someOtherLibrary
        return someOtherLibrary.doSomething(data)

#Application observers
class Observer:
    def OnOutput(self, output):
        pass

#Search window, which uses some classifier during the operation
class SearchingWindow:
    def __init__(self, clf, negativeResult=0):
        from collections import deque 
        self.observers = observers 
        self.classifier = clf  #now, the classifier is injected
        self.buffer = deque(maxlen=1000)
        self.negativeResult = negativeResult

    def AddData(self, data):
        self.buffer.extend(data)

    def UpdateObservers(self, output):
        for observer in self.observers:
            observer.OnOutput(output)


    def __call__(self, data):
        # The main entry point for all the processing
        self.searchWindow.AddData(data)
        self.classifier.Train(data)  #The main processing requires training
        for output in self:
           self.UpdateObservers(output) 

    def __iter__(self):
         start = 0
         step = 1
         stop = 3*step
         while notDone:
            start, stop, step = self.GetNextStartStopStep(start, stop, step)
            for i in range(start,stop,step):
                dataSubset = self.buffer[start:stop]
                result1, result2, ..., resultN = self.classifier.Classify(dataSubset)
                if result1 != self.negativeResult:
                    yield dataSubset
```